# How to set each user time-zone from a collection of users in MySQL query base.

Tags: mysql, timezone

Question: How to set each user time-zone from a collection of users in MySQL query base.

I tried out one MySQL query to change the time-zone for each user.
By using this query:- "SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;" it changes all the users time-zone.

Please guide me for setting each user time-zones from the query base.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this in MySQL. You should do it in the view and store in  MySQL the UTC time.

When you display the time for each user in the view. Using for example php   you take the UTC time from your database and adjust it to the user time zone and store the time zone of each user in a table in your database